# Efficient test for pythagorean triples in modulo integer space

Tags: c, algorithm, conditional-statements, integer-overflow

I was wondering what the most effective formula, for testing if three numbers are a pythagorean triple is.
Just as a reminder: a pythagorean triple are three integers where `a²+b²=c²`.

I mean not the most effective formula in terms of time, but a formula that is the most efficient in terms of not causing an overflow on a specific integer(lets say **32-bit unsigned int**).

I was trying a bit with rearrangements of `a*a + b*b == c*c`:

> Let's assume `a<=b<c`, then the best formula I could get to is:
>   `2b*(c-b) == (a+b-c) * (a-b+c)`
>   with this formula can be proven, that the right side is smaller than `a*c` and so should be the left side, but `a*c` doesn't look like a huge improvement of `c*c`.

So my question is, if there is a better formula for this conditional that works with bigger numbers without overflowing an integer space. The execution time of the formula doesn't matter that much, besides it should be O(1).

PS: I don't know if I should post such a question here or on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but to me it seems to be more about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about formulas/algorithms, not programming.

Comment: @Olaf so should I post it on Mathematics SE?

Comment: PS: since when are questions about algorithms off-topic?

Comment: I do not know the policy of that site, so I'm careful to recommend. Btw: if you want "unlimited" integers, try Python. If speed is not an issue, it is the swiss army knife of programming.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf for the advise, but I think with Python it's impossible to solve it in O(1) as the algorithm slows down with bigger numbers.

Comment: Hmm, you might be right, but as given, it is lacking more inforamtion. E.g. what is the possible range of values? Many languages have more than one integer type. I also see no specific relation to C.

Comment: Complexity is not a matter of the programming language/implementation or execution speed, but the algorithm! Either is is O(1) or it is not.

Comment: @Olaf you're right but still Python would be kind of O(ln(n)) because the code is translated to an algorithm that slows down with bigger numbers.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth Hope this helps.

Comment: @Olaf "Software algorithms" are explicitly mentioned as on-topic in the help center.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth If a, b and c fit into O(1) bits, then a^2, b^2 and c^2 fit into 2 * O(1) = O(1) bits too, so your argument is not really valid

Comment: @NiklasB. this explains also Riccis answer, but I'm actually searching a solution where just integers of the specified size are used. And there should be just primitive maths like `+-*/^&|%` and no tricks to pack the numbers in bigger integers, so that the solution is also applicable to any other integer size.

Comment: Also by just packing them in bigger types, there is no limit and you end up with some O(ln(n)) solution.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth I'm just saying, just by specifying that the input is represented using 32 bits per number and intermediate computations should not require more than 32 bits, you don't really force any kind of creative solution. Because you can easily implement 64 bit integers using 32 bit integers, in O(1) per operation, as Ricci's answer shows. Seems however that one of the answers is what you were probably looking for

Comment: I'm thinking to accept Sumeets answer but I'm not sure if it works always(until MAX_INT/2 or whatever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** If you need to have 32bit integers all the way down then you can just modify the math to fit your requirement. To keep it simple I do the math (squaring and summing) on 16bit chunks of data and use a struct that contains 2 unsigned ints as the result.

http://ideone.com/er2TaS

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct u64 {
    unsigned int lo;
    unsigned int hi;
    bool of;
};
u64 square(unsigned int a) {
    u64 result;
    unsigned int alo = (a & 0xffff);
    unsigned int ahi = (a >> 16);
    unsigned int aalo = alo * alo;
    unsigned int aami = alo * ahi;
    unsigned int aahi = ahi * ahi;
    unsigned int aa1 = aalo & 0xffff;
    unsigned int aa2 = (aalo >> 16) + (aami & 0xffff) + (aami & 0xffff);
    unsigned int aa3 = (aa2 >> 16) + (aami >> 16) + (aami >> 16) + (aahi & 0xffff);
    unsigned int aa4 = (aa3 >> 16) + (aahi >> 16);
    result.lo = (aa1 & 0xffff) | ((aa2 & 0xffff) << 16);
    result.hi = (aa3 & 0xffff) | (aa4 << 16);
    result.of = false; // 0xffffffff^2 can't overflow
    return result;
}
u64 sum(u64 a, u64 b) {
    u64 result;
    unsigned int a1 = a.lo & 0xffff;
    unsigned int a2 = a.lo >> 16;
    unsigned int a3 = a.hi & 0xffff;
    unsigned int a4 = a.hi >> 16;
    unsigned int b1 = b.lo & 0xffff;
    unsigned int b2 = b.lo >> 16;
    unsigned int b3 = b.hi & 0xffff;
    unsigned int b4 = b.hi >> 16;
    unsigned int s1 = a1 + b1;
    unsigned int s2 = a2 + b2 + (s1 >> 16);
    unsigned int s3 = a3 + b3 + (s2 >> 16);
    unsigned int s4 = a4 + b4 + (s3 >> 16);
    result.lo = (s1 & 0xffff) | ((s2 & 0xffff) << 16);
    result.hi = (s3 & 0xffff) | ((s4 & 0xffff) << 16);
    result.of = (s4 > 0xffff ? true : false);
    return result;
}
bool isTriple(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c) {
    u64 aa = square(a);
    u64 bb = square(b);
    u64 cc = square(c);
    u64 aabb = sum(aa, bb);
    return aabb.lo == cc.lo && aabb.hi == cc.hi && aabb.of == false;
}
int main() {
    cout << isTriple(3,4,5) << endl;
    cout << isTriple(2800,9600,10000) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Conerting your 32bit integers to 64bit longs or even floating point doubles would **edit** *reduce* the chance of overflow and continue being, programmatically, O(1) since all the major architectures (x86, ARM, etc) have int to double conversion op codes at the low level and casting up to a long from int is also an O(1) operation.

```
bool isTriple(int a, int b, int c) {
long long bigA = a;
long long bigB = b;
long long bigC = c;
return bigA * bigA + bigB * bigB == bigC * bigC;
}
```

Comment: But the problem persists: I have a margin in that architecture/integer class, wich I want to optimize.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth - If the integers are large enough even an addition can cause an overflow

Comment: True, but the numbers must be much larger to cause an overflow with an addition than with a multiplication or square.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth - breaking the math into unsigned 32bit chunks to avoid overflows in any situation will also work

Comment: "Converting your 32bit integers to ... floating point doubles ..." is a potential problem as `double` * `double` may lose exact product representation.

Comment: @chux - that's right, doubles are only integer precise to the number of bits in their mantissa, perhaps 80bit long doubles would be sufficient. Even an unsigned long long will still over flow (0xFFFFFFFF ^ 2) * 2. For these reasons I edited my answer to show a solution that is correct over all UINT32.

Comment: Not quite that what I'm looking for, but still a nice solution. +1

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it works and answers the question correctly, it is not the kind of solution I would like, but I think there is no such solution. Also this answer is by far better than an answer where the code doesn't work. If anyone else finds a better solution, feel free to answer and I will accept their solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think little rearrangement would help a lot.

```
a²+b²=c² 

can be written as b²=c²-a²

which is b² = (c-a)(c+a)

and hence we arrive at

b/(c+a) = (c-a)/b

or (c+a)/b = b/(c-a)
```

Now using the above equation, you do not need to compute squares.

So we must do this

```
  if(((c+a)/(double)b)==((double)(b)/(c-a)))
    printf("Yes it is pythagorean triples");
  else printf("No it is not");
```

Comment: This approach may be inaccurate if you calculate those quotients. If you reduce the fractions and test for equality then it will no longer be O(1).

Comment: I have thought of something similar before, but I think the flaw here is that you can't be sure that `b` is divisible by `c+a` and `c-a` is divisible by `b`. And if it's not it will be rounded and give false positives.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth Tell me the language u are using.

Comment: I tagged the question `c`, but I think the language doesn't matter a lot as long as it uses integers that can overflow and are _not_ automatically converted to floating point numbers.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth [Euclid's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) shows that you are correct!

Comment: @Sumeet 3/10 != 2/3. And the problem of determining if 2 non-integer types are equal still exists.

Comment: @MichaelSPriz It is when you are using C language and the numbers are integers.

Comment: I still do not think that this is correct. You still would need to determine if (b%(c+a))/(c+a) and ((c-a)%b)/b are equal.

Comment: C+A could still overflow. Example: if the last 2 bits of C are set and the 2nd to last bit of A 11b + 01b = [1]00b

Comment: @Louis Ricci so this method appears to be limited to `0<=a<=b<c<=UINT_MAX/2`.  Much better than OP's original limit of about `sqrt(UINT_MAX)`.

Comment: @chux - I proposed a more complex (operation wise) solution that will work on all UINT32's, but if undefined results are acceptable for the very large numbers than this concise solution is great.

Comment: Finally got time to test it, it is a really nice solution and would be great if it would work, but @MichaelSPriz was absolutely right, this code gives false positives(for now I don't know if there are false negatives to), the smallest false positive I could find is: `a=6,b=7,c=9`, which is clearly not a pythagorean triple.

Comment: Yeah not so good, there are false negatives too: `a=5,b=12,c=13`, this answer also isn't proven and there is no logic that it works, following math rules @MichaelSPriz 's solution should be right, but not an improvement to the solution I proposed.

Comment: @KlausPrinoth fine i am removing my answer.It was good of you to point out the mistake. Constructive criticism is what i like.

Comment: @MichaelSPriz ok i am removing my answer,

Comment: @KlausPrinoth I think now, it will work for all cases.

Comment: You don't have to remove your answer, you showed research effort and got up-voted for that, now it also works, but to convert the integers to doubles is still not solution I'm seeking.

Comment: Note: case where `c+a` overflows does not look like this code will work.